# php if else issue detected

Tags: php, if-statement, web, prestashop

I'm trying to create an `if else` string on a `php` of prestashop,

I'm trying to make my site to run a code if the page is discount but run the other code if it is not... but dreamweaver says there are errors, what's wrong in it?

Thank you

this is the code

```
if ($page_name == 'discount')
{
 public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'address',
    'primary' => 'id_address',
    'fields' => array(
        'id_customer' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_manufacturer' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_supplier' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_warehouse' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_country' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => false),
        'id_state' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId'),
        'alias' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'company' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 64),
        'lastname' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'firstname' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'vat_number' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName'),
        'address1' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAddress', 'required' => false, 'size' => 128),
        'address2' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAddress', 'size' => 128),
        'postcode' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPostCode', 'size' => 12),
        'city' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isCityName', 'required' => false, 'size' => 64),
        'other' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMessage', 'size' => 300),
        'phone' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPhoneNumber', 'size' => 32),
        'phone_mobile' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPhoneNumber', 'size' => 32),
        'dni' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isDniLite', 'size' => 16),
        'deleted' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_add' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_upd' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
    ),
);
}

else
{
     public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'address',
    'primary' => 'id_address',
    'fields' => array(
        'id_customer' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_manufacturer' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_supplier' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_warehouse' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_country' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
        'id_state' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId'),
        'alias' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'company' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 64),
        'lastname' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'firstname' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'vat_number' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName'),
        'address1' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAddress', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
        'address2' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAddress', 'size' => 128),
        'postcode' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPostCode', 'size' => 12),
        'city' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isCityName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 64),
        'other' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMessage', 'size' => 300),
        'phone' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPhoneNumber', 'size' => 32),
        'phone_mobile' =>        array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPhoneNumber', 'size' => 32),
        'dni' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isDniLite', 'size' => 16),
        'deleted' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_add' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_upd' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
    ),
);
}
```

Comment: You can't define class properties using if else, not to mention that you can't define class properties using dynamic values. Use a [setter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: Also, when asking a question it is better to always provide the error message if there is one.

Comment: What you could do is,
Make your class property as `public static $definition = [];`. In your constructor you can check your `if` condition and populate value for `$definition`

Answer (score 2):

You can't define a public static member like that. You declare it in the class then initialize it in the method:

```
class X {
    public static $definition;
    function method()
    {
        if ($page_name == 'discount') {
            $definition = array (
...
            );
        }

        else {
            $definition = array (
                            'table' => 'address',
                            'primary' => 'id_address',
                            'fields' => array (
```

Comment: so i decide a class name then where there are the three dots i put my code?

Comment: The three dots mean I have removed some of your code to avoid a long message. Why are you using public static if you are not in a class?

Comment: i basically lnow nothing of php but i need to make some required fields not required only on that discount page so i was tring to use an if on my localhost... so that code is already complete or ihave to add something?

Comment: Ask someone who knows php or learn at least some basics. You need to know what is a class before making such changes.

Comment: You should hire a professional if it's really important.